# Oracle Query to rollup by the Flag

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a req to roll up the amounts based on ID Columns and Flag.

My Input:-

```
**ordr | item| amt|flg |dtl_item**
637262  1   98.58   Y   1
637262  2   1182.7  Y   1
637262  2   2365.4  Y   2
661209  1   0       Y   1
661209  1   960     N   1.1
661209  2   0       Y   1
661209  2   96      N   1.1
```

My output:-

```
**ordr | item| amt|flg |dtl_item**
637262  1   98.58   Y   1
637262  2   1182.7  Y   1
637262  2   2365.4  Y   2
661209  1   960     Y   1
661209  2   96      Y   1
```

1) I would need to rollup the `amt` to the record with `flg='Y'` for each `ordr,item and dtl_item`.

I tried to write the query like below and filter out flg='N' records, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
select ordr,item, sum(amt), max(flg), dtl_num
group by ordr,item,dtl_num
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output doesn't make any sense, and has no correlation with your description of what you want.

Comment: Simple `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE flg = 'Y'`?

Comment: @lad2025 How does that give you the last line `661209 | 2 | 96 | Y |  1`?

Comment: @Racil - Basically I would need to rollup the amounts to root_prod level which means flg = 'Y'. If there are multiple dtl_item with flg = 'Y' for each  ordr,item then  no need to rollup. If there are multiple dtl_item with flg = 'Y' and 'N' for each  ordr,item then all the values with flg = 'N' needs to rollup to flag = 'Y' records.

Comment: Are dtl_num 1 and 1.1 two different dtl_num or the same dtl_num?

Comment: @kc2018 - they are 2 different dtl_num.

Answer (score 0):

The following finds all the rows with `Y` flag and add the amount with `N` flag for each order/item. It won't work if an order/item has multiple `Y` flag rows and one or more `N` flag rows.

```
select ty.ordr, ty.item, 
coalesce(ty.amt,0) + coalesce(tn.amt,0) as amt,
ty.flag, ty.dtl_item
from
( select ordr, item, amt, flag, dtl_item 
  from test where flag = 'Y' ) ty
left join
( select ordr, item, sum(amt) as amt
  from test where flag = 'N'
  group by ordr, item) tn
on ty.ordr = tn.ordr and ty.item = tn.item
order by ty.ordr, ty.item
```